# Can not connect to Consul DNS from the other nodes

Tags: dns, consul

I setup Consul Master on 192.168.1.191 and on Agent at 192.168.1.198.

And I try with `dig` command in Consul Master, it works:

```
# dig @192.168.1.191 -p 53 kafka.service.consul. ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.1.191 -p 53 kafka.service.consul. ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43471
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kafka.service.consul.      IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
kafka.service.consul.   0   IN  A   192.168.1.86

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.191#53(192.168.1.191)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 04 08:43:20 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74
```

Why? It seems that Consul does not work with the request from the other nodes.
Any help will be appreciated.

But, when I try `dig` command in Consul Agent, I got an timeout message:

```
# dig @192.168.1.191 -p 53 kafka.service.consul. ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.1.191 -p 53 kafka.service.consul. ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

And the below is the output of TCPDump command on Consul Master:

```
# tcpdump -i eth1 udp port 53 -vv -X
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
08:35:42.282202 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50130, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 77)
    192.168.1.198.46137 > redis.domain: [udp sum ok] 48769+ [1au] ANY? kafka.service.consul. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 (49)
    0x0000:  4500 004d c3d2 0000 4011 31f8 c0a8 01c6  E..M....@.1.....
    0x0010:  c0a8 01bf b439 0035 0039 6e55 be81 0120  .....9.5.9nU....
    0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0001 056b 6166 6b61 0773  .........kafka.s
    0x0030:  6572 7669 6365 0663 6f6e 7375 6c00 00ff  ervice.consul...
    0x0040:  0001 0000 2910 0000 0000 0000 00         ....)........
08:35:47.284122 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50899, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 77)
    192.168.1.198.46137 > redis.domain: [udp sum ok] 48769+ [1au] ANY? kafka.service.consul. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 (49)
    0x0000:  4500 004d c6d3 0000 4011 2ef7 c0a8 01c6  E..M....@.......
    0x0010:  c0a8 01bf b439 0035 0039 6e55 be81 0120  .....9.5.9nU....
    0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0001 056b 6166 6b61 0773  .........kafka.s
    0x0030:  6572 7669 6365 0663 6f6e 7375 6c00 00ff  ervice.consul...
    0x0040:  0001 0000 2910 0000 0000 0000 00         ....)........
08:35:52.284451 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51652, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 77)
    192.168.1.198.46137 > redis.domain: [udp sum ok] 48769+ [1au] ANY? kafka.service.consul. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 (49)
    0x0000:  4500 004d c9c4 0000 4011 2c06 c0a8 01c6  E..M....@.,.....
    0x0010:  c0a8 01bf b439 0035 0039 6e55 be81 0120  .....9.5.9nU....
    0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0001 056b 6166 6b61 0773  .........kafka.s
    0x0030:  6572 7669 6365 0663 6f6e 7375 6c00 00ff  ervice.consul...
    0x0040:  0001 0000 2910 0000 0000 0000 00         ....)........
```

Comment: Each consul agent (client and server) has the dns interface. So you should be able to call your local consul agent to get a response instead of going to the master (consul will take care of that for you). Maybe you can make it work that way?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will implement that way. Consul is great!